# Is there a way to delete highlighted columns?

Tags: excel

I'd like to run a macro/excel function that deletes columns that are highlighted. Is there an easy function do this?

We need to populate duplicate fields for internal procedure but need to remove the duplicates for external parties

Comment: Sure - *any* highlight, or a specific color? Also, what's making them highlighted, is there a condition/rule that tells you which to highlight, or is highlighting set manually? What have you tried so far?

Comment: A specific color highlight. Say "Yellow" for every duplicate column. Manual edit

Comment: If the highlighting is set manually, couldn't you just select the columns using `Ctrl+click` and then right-click -> delete?  (instead of highlighting)

Comment: We need to populate the highlighted columns initially for internal procedure. Just to delete them for external distro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have an entire column highlighted in yellow, this will just check to see if the cell in row 1 is yellow. If so, it'll delete the column.

```
Sub deleteYellowColumns()
Dim lastCol As Long, i As Long
Dim ws as Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1") ' Change this as necessary
lastCol = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For i = lastCol To 1 Step -1
    If ws.Cells(1, i).Interior.Color = 65535 Then ws.Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Delete
Next i

End Sub
```